# Gitlab runner tons of errors when trying to use shell executor

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed the runners using the `docker` executor, but then later realized I actually needed the `shell` executor for layer caching... However now I just keep running into so many errors trying to get the runner to work...

```
sudo gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=17362 revision=79704081 version=16.0.1
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
affiliate-processor-1                               Executor=shell Token=******************* URL=https://gitlab.com
affiliate-processor-1                               Executor=shell Token=******************* URL=https://gitlab.com
gitlab-runner-final                                 Executor=shell Token=******************* URL=https://gitlab.com
```

And the journal logs:

```
sudo journalctl -u gitlab-runner --follow
-- Logs begin at Sat 2023-05-27 18:43:05 UTC. --
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: Running in system-mode.                           
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]:                                                   
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: [session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: Initializing executor providers                     builds=0
Jun 05 12:29:01 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=m5Q9_Nc_6
Jun 05 12:29:03 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=m5Q9_Nc_6
Jun 05 12:29:04 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: ERROR: Checking for jobs... forbidden               runner=m5Q9_Nc_6
Jun 05 12:29:04 affiliate-processor-1 gitlab-runner[17177]: ERROR: Runner "https://gitlab.com************************" is unhealthy and will be disabled for 1h0m0s seconds!  unhealthy_requests=3 unhealthy_requests_limit=3
```

How can I fix this?

Some more issues, `systemctl status gitlab-runner.service` shows:

```
/usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/chris --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --user gitlab-runner
```

Why is it using my PERSONAL home directory as the working directory??? Surely it rather uses some system directory instead or the gitlab-runner home directory?!?!

---

OKAY I have uninstalled the old runners which seemed to be the cause of the issue... But now I have these pipeline errors:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/chris/builds/onty8Erw6’: Permission denied
```

?!?!?!? WHY IS IT USING THE `/home/chris` directory?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I had to just set the following in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
[[runners]]
  ...
  builds_dir = "/home/gitlab-runner/build/"
```

This parameter does not change the value in  `/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service` **until** a build is triggered (it seems)...